# DJANGO REST API ---Javascript function not generating right PK

Tags: javascript, python, django, angular, rest

Working on Django REST API in which a dog is shown to a user based on preferences (age, gender, size).  A user can either like or dislike a dog.  They are then shown the next dog (assuming they haven't seen it yet) based on their set preferences.

The app is showing user the first dog (based on preferences-UserPref model), but when they go to click either like or dislike it is not moving to the next dog and generating a Not Found error like this:

Not Found: /api/dog/undefined/disliked/next

where the undefined should be the PK for the next dog

Therefore either my python logic is not generating the right PK (as noted by 'undefined' in the error code) or for some reason the javascript code is not getting the right formatted number for the PK.  Just not sure what the issue might be.

Here are my models:

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image_filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Unknown Breed')
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=1)
    size = models.CharField(choices=SIZE, max_length=2)

    @property
    def get_image_url(self):
        return self.image_filename.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class UserDog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    dog = models.ForeignKey(Dog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'dog')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.user, self.dog, self.get_status_display())


class UserPref(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='b,y,a,s')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='m,f')
    size = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='s,m,l,xl')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} preferences'.format(self.user)
```

And View corresponding to the Dog Selection for Next

```
AGES = {
    'b': list(range(0, 6)),
    'y': list(range(6, 18)),
    'a': list(range(18, 72)),
    's': list(range(72, 192))
}


def get_ages(keys='b,y,a,s'):
    """Returns age ranges in years."""
    data = []
    for key in keys.split(','):
        data.extend(AGES[key])
    return data



class DogFilterView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.DogSerializer

    def get_ids(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is not None:
            return [userdog.dog.pk for userdog in queryset]
        return []

    def filter_pref(self, dog_filter, user_prefs):
        userdog_query = models.UserDog.objects.filter(user=user_prefs.user.pk
                                                      ).select_related('dog')
        ages = get_ages(user_prefs.age)
        queryset = models.Dog.objects.filter(
            gender__in = user_prefs.gender.split(','),
            size__in = user_prefs.size.split(','),
            age__in = ages
        )
        if dog_filter not in STATUSES:
            dogs = self.get_ids(userdog_query)
            queryset = queryset.exclude(pk__in=dogs)
        else:
            userdog_query = userdog_query.filter(status=dog_filter[0])
            dogs = self.get_ids(userdog_query)
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk__in=dogs)

        return queryset.order_by('pk')

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        dog_filter = self.kwargs.get('dog_filter')
        # Get user preferences
        user_prefs = get_object_or_404(models.UserPref, user=user)
        # Get age ranges(months) based on user preference selections
        queryset = self.filter_pref(dog_filter, user_prefs)
        return queryset

    def get_object(self):
        pk = int(self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        # Filter the query for the NEXT dog by pk.
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(
            pk__gt=pk
        )
        obj = queryset.first()
        if not obj:
            raise Http404
        return obj
```

And then my REGEX:

```
url(r'^api/dog/(?P<pk>-?\d+)/(?P<dog_filter>liked|disliked|undecided)/next/$',
        DogFilterView.as_view(),
        name='dog-filter-detail'),
```

my Serializer for Dog Class:

```
class DogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'name',
            'image_filename',
            'breed',
            'age',
            'gender',
            'size'
        )
        model = models.Dog
```

Also note there is a part of Javascript that I didn't write here that i thought maybe was something to examine but not sure---this is the function that gets next dog:

```
getNext: function () {
    this.serverRequest = $.ajax({
      url: `api/dog/${ this.state.details ? this.state.details.id : -1 }/${ this.state.filter }/next/`,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      headers: TokenAuth.getAuthHeader()
    }).done(function (data) {
      this.setState({ details: data, message: undefined });
    }.bind(this)).fail(function (response) {
      var message = null;
      if (response.status == 404) {
        if (this.state.filter == "undecided") {
          message = "No dogs matched your preferences.";
        } else {
          message = `You don't have any ${ this.state.filter } dogs.`;
        }
      } else {
        message = response.error;
      }
      this.setState({ message: message, details: undefined });
    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: `undefined` is a javascript primitive. What makes you think there's something wrong with the python api? The javascript expression at the end of your question would cause such an error if either `this.state.details` is false/missing or `this.state.details.id` is missing.

Comment: Because it should be generating a value for the <pk>. There are 30 some odd dogs in database and even if all preferences selected it is not advancing to next dog.

Comment: Where is the code that implements "next"? Python doesn't have `undefined`, so the error must be somewhere in your javascript.

Comment: In any case, it's impossible for us to know how your api is supposed to work, since you have not included the serializer class. [mcve]

Comment: Ok understood.  Code might get overwhelming so copying my git repository here:  https://github.com/pythoncreate/pugorugh

Comment: Note--added Serializer class, and the next function from JS in original post

Comment: `this.state.details` does not contain the required data to build a valid url. You should raise an error if that happens, instead of submitting an api call to an incorrect url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of endlessly looking at this, i figured it out.  I was not passing the 'id' field to the DogSerializer, thus, the pk was not being passed.  Wow, thank god for that.